# postgresql: how to add column which shows time difference between the two rows

Tags: postgresql

I have some table with `time` columns

```
id  | time
----|-------------------
1   | 2021-2-2 10:21:00
2   | 2021-2-2 10:24:00
3   | 2021-2-2 10:27:00
4   | 2021-2-2 10:29:00
```

Now i want to add another column which shows time difference and another column which will add status based on the difference

```
id  | time              | diff  | status
----|----------------------------------
1   | 2021-2-2 10:21:00 | None  | None
2   | 2021-2-2 10:24:00 | 3:00  | 1
3   | 2021-2-2 10:26:00 | 2:00  | 0
4   | 2021-2-2 10:29:00 | 3:00  | 1
```

```
status = if diff >= 3 then 1 else 0
```

How can i do this. I have to get the data for the last seven days and then get this final table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LAG`:

```
SELECT id, time,
       EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time - LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY time)) / 60 AS diff,
       (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time - LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY time)) / 60 >= 3)::int AS status
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY time;
```

Comment: can you bit explain `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time - LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY time) / 60)`

Comment: @Santhosh It takes the difference between the current and previous timestamp, extracts seconds, and then converts to minutes.  Somewhat ugly, but this is how Postgres works.

Comment: can you break up ` EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time - LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY time) / 60) `   bit this and explain. it will be very helpful

Comment: The difference between time and lag of time is an intermediate result.  We use `EXTRACT` to get that difference in seconds, then we divide by 60 to get minutes.